# Updating Exchange 2010 from SP1 to SP3

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

I've been tasked with updating our standalone Exchange 2010 SP1 server to SP3. I'm looking for any gotcha's, etc on this. ;) It is a virtual machine so I'm able to make a backup before I begin.

Already when I run the Readiness Checks I get an error in Orgainization Prereq.. Cannot find at least 1 domain controller running Server 2003. We have five total domain controllers all running 2008 R2. The exchange server can connect to them all.

Anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The checker will report that if the domain controllers aren't running the remote registry service and/or firewall issues. You should be fine on your upgrade, just take a snapshot/backup before just in case.

Comment: Can I force it to proceed? After the prereqs fail my only options are back, retry and cancel.

Comment: I don't think so, SP3 makes schema changes to activedirectory. You need to verify you can connect to the domain controllers and you have the necessary permissions to make schema changes. If the prereq check is failing, you need to address that.